# Yii2: How to simply include and use in controllers the Stripe php lib?

Tags: php, yii2, stripe-payments

So far I've used composer which puts the lib underneath the vendor folder. 
It goes like this : vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib

From there I'm bit lost on how I should declare the namespace (i guess in config/web.php underneath components). The namespace declared in the Stripe.php class file is Stripe.

In the controllers I would like to use it like shown in the examples on the Stripe site.

```

```
// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
        $charge = \StripeLib\Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
          "currency" => "eur",
          "source" => $token,
          "description" => "payinguser@example.com")
        );
    } catch(\StripeLib\Error\Card $e) {
      // The card has been declined
        echo "The card has been declined. Please, try again.";
    }
```

```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @david s Yii2 framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with this. I added the Stripe library to my composer file

```
"stripe/stripe-php" : "2.*"
```

that created /vendor/stripe/stripe-php

The stripe library uses just Stripe as the namespace. So then in my controller I put

```
use Stripe\Stripe;  
use Stripe\Charge;
```

Then I was able to do things like

```
Stripe::setApiKey(Yii::$app->params['sk_test'])
```

and

```
try {
    $charge = Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => round(100*100,0), // amount in cents, again
      "currency" => "usd",
      "card" => $token,
      "description" => 'description',
      ));
     $paid = true;                

} // end try
```

So far so good ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here how it goes. After including the lib using composer, you can find the stripe class under vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/stripe. So, in my controller I did this

```
use app\stripe\stripe-php\lib\Stripe;
```

But it didn't work because of the hyphen so I had to rename the folder stripe-php into stripephp (I know that is not good AT ALL) because it won't be updated with composer i guess.

Finally, I have this at the beginning of my controller

```
use app\stripe\stripephp\lib\Stripe;
```

Then in my action I use something like this

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Yii::$app->stripe->privateKey);
        //we got the token, we must then charge the customer
        // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];


        // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
        try {
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
              "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
              ...
```

Dont forget to put your private/public keys in your config file.

If by any mean you have a better solution (more elegant) please, you're welcome.